# How to implement IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler in Orchard CMS?

Tags: authentication, permissions, handler, orchardcms

I have difficulties with the implementation of `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler` in Orchard CMS.

The issue here is that i want to check for specific permissions (permissions defined by my module) but the parameters of the handler methods (type `Orchard.Security.CheckAccessContext`) do not provide the feature name of the permission being checked.

Why is that so or is this a bug?

Surely i can name my permission like `MyModuleName.PermissionName` or use another type of name encoding but i think this is not practical as we already have the feature name linked to the permission in the DB for example.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please provide the code you tried, and explain how it fails to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, after reconsidering my approach and watching the call stack the issue is no more an issue.

My question was based on the thinking that i need to compare `aContext.Permission.Name` provided by e.g. `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler.Complete()` with the permission names of my module.

But since the instance `aContext.Permission` provided by by e.g. `IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler.Complete()` is the instance passed to the related `IAuthorizationService.TryCheckAccess()` call i can do a simple comparison like

```
if (aContext.Permission == MyModule.Permission.PermissionA) { ... }
```

and it works because both instances have the same pointer address.